# Make ExtJS singleton return object using Ext.Ajax.request

Tags: javascript, extjs, singleton, return

Well, I am very new to javascript and for sure, I am very new at extJS, which is a Sencha JS framework. What I want to do I think is very simple, but I do not know to much about js.

This is the js file I've been provided:

```
Ext.define('app.util.UserWGroupInfo', {
    alternateClassName: ['UserInfo', 'WGroupInfo'],
    singleton: true,

    /**
     * Default information to be shown / displayed
     */
    statics: {
        userData: {
            'username':                 'User Name',
            'phoneNumber':              'Phone',
            'firstName':                'First Name',
            'lastName':                 'Last Name',
            'emailAddress':             'Email',
            'address.addressLine1':     'Address',
            'address.city':             'City',
            'address.stateOrProv':      'State'
        },
        wGroupData: {
            'name':                     'Name',
            'type':                     'Type',
            'description':              'Description',
            'phoneNumber':              'Phone',
            'poc':                      'POC'
        }
    },

    /**
     * Holder for the data to display
     * @type {Object}
     */
    dataToDisplay: {

    },

    /**
     * display a popup on no data retrieved
     * @type {Boolean} [true]
     */
    displayMsg: true,

    /**
     * Gets data of an user from the server
     * 
     * @param {String} userInfo, consider passing "usid:name"
     * @param {Boolean} double set true to check Like User&WGroup
     */
    getUserInfo: function(userInfo, displayMsg) {

        if (Ext.isEmpty(userInfo)) {
            return;
        }

        userInfo = userInfo.split(':');
        var user = userInfo[0] + ':' + + userInfo[1];

        //Note: to retrieve tooltip, set defaults data
        this.dataToDisplay = this.statics().userData;
        this.typeSearch = "User";

        if (displayMsg) {
            this.displayMsg = displayMsg;
        }

        this.getSysAdminObj('users', user);
    },

    /**
     * Gets data of a workgroup from the server
     * 
     * @param {String} wGroupInfo, consider passing "wgid:name"
     * @param {Boolean} double set true to check Like User&WGroup
     */
    getWGroupInfo: function(wGroupInfo, displayMsg) {

        if (Ext.isEmpty(wGroupInfo)) {
            return;
        }

        wGroupInfo = wGroupInfo.split(':');
        var wGroup = wGroupInfo[0] + ':' + wGroupInfo[1];

        //Note: to retrieve tooltip, set default data
        this.dataToDisplay = this.statics().wGroupData;
        this.typeSearch = "Work Group";

        if (displayMsg) {
            this.displayMsg = displayMsg;
        }

        this.getSysAdminObj('workgroups', wGroup);
    },

    getDataInfo: function() {
        return this.dataInfo;
    },

    /**
     * Retrieve a SysAdmin object to perform a connection to the server side.
     * 
     * @param {String} type. Consider as possible values: "users" or "workgroups"
     * @param {String} info
     */    
    getSysAdminObj: function(type, info) {
        var me = this;

        Ext.Ajax.request ({
            url:        '../rest/sysadmin/' + type + '/' + info,
            method:     'GET',
            scope:      me,
            async:      false,
            callback:   me.storeInfo
        });
    },

    /**
     * Map information retrieved to the dataInfo object.
     * 
     * Before storing the data, it is necessary to check if the search should be executed as user or workgroup.
     */
    storeInfo: function(o, s, r) {
        if ( !s ) {
            if (this.displayMsg) {
                Logger.notify('User Info Loading', 'Failed to load extra user info');
            }
            this.errorResponse = true;
            return;
        };

        this.errorResponse = false;
        var obtainedData = XmlConverter.unmarshal(r);
        this.dataInfo = obtainedData;
    }

});
```

I've been provided with this class, which is a singleton, what it does? It retrieves user information and workgroup information based on call made to a REST service (Java), I use a "SysAdminObject" which is a "js" which handles some behaviors of the connection, and finally, I use a "Ext.Ajax.request" to get the data from server. When I execute the callback I can see the function "storeInfo" which sets the data into a variable (well, that's what it seems to be doing). Then I can handle the dataInfo variable which contains all the information I need and I return it with method:"getDataInfo". Is there any way to just return the data directly whenever you call the service? I mean in java, for example:

```
public Object getUserInfo() {
  Object obj = null;
  obj = getFromServer();
  return obj;
}
```

Is there any way to have this behavior with extJS and Javascript?

Thanks in advance for your time and help. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `return` of the ajax request is handled by whatever method you assign as the `callback` function. In this example, it is handled by the `storeInfo()` function.

The closest you can get to your Java example is:

```
getUserInfo: function() {
    getSysAdminObj();
    return this.dataInfo;
}
```

The `getSysAdminObj()` function gets the data and stores it in `this.dataInfo`, as shown in your code. Since the server call is not asynchronous (as set by the line `async: false`), the javascript code waits until the server call returns the data, so you know that `this.dataInfo` will contain the requested data. However, if you set `async: true`, the line `return this.dataInfo` in my code above could executed before `this.dataInfo` is set.

Many times, it is preferable to not wait for a server request to complete (since this halts any code in the browser from running until the potentially-slow server call returns). So, then `async` would be set to `true`. In order to handle this properly, you have to make sure that the code following the server call isn't depending on the results of the server call, and instead, anything that depends on those results must be placed in the `callback` function mentioned above.

The difficulty is, returning something from the `callback` function won't return that value to the method that made the original server call. So, you can't just move `return this.dataInfo` into the `callback` function and expect it to work. Instead, you need to use listeners and events. The `callback` function should fire an event that tells whatever code is listening that the data has been retrieved, and so the listener can do whatever it is it should be doing with that code.

For example, lets say you make an ExtJS grid panel, and you want it to display the SysAdmin data that your code is retrieving. You would add an event to your singleton shown above, and the `storeInfo` function would fire that event, instead of storing the data, and pass the data into the event as a parameter. Attached to your singleton would be a listener for that event, which would take in the data as its parameter, and would then load that data into the grid panel.

I know I touched on a bunch of topics in this, but I wasn't sure what you already knew. You can search for more info on these topics if you aren't familiar with them. I hope this is helpful, and can get you pointed in the right direction. As you can see, working in JavaScript has some important differences from Java.

Also, the ExtJS docs are very helpful, so check those out if you haven't already. This links to the latest version http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api

Comment: thank you very much, well explained and helped me to realize what I have to do. Thanks!